# I am working on a JDA Bot. However when i add more than one args to react to MessageReactionAddEvent and MessageReceived event,it doesnt work

Tags: java, discord-jda

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event,MessageReaction reaction) {
        String[] messagelements = event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split("\\s+");

    if (messagelements[0].equalsIgnoreCase("=")) {
        if (messagelements[1].equalsIgnoreCase("ping")){
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("pong");
        }
    }
    if (reaction.getReactionEmote().equals(":one:"){
        reaction.getChannel().sendMessage("one").queue();
    }
}
```

So when i add multiple types of event listeners to a method, The discord bot doesnt react, however  when i remove the MessageReactionAddEvent, it starts to react again. Why does it refuse to execute the code when a there is a reaction? I have tried splitting the two events into different classes, and added @Override to the front of each class, however, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Each event has to have its own event listener override:

```java
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
  ...
}

@Override
public void onMessageReactionAdd(MessageReactionAddEvent event) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I do remember trying this but the @Override usually has an error message saying that it cannot be Overriden from the superclass

Comment: @noobdev you need to actually extend ListenerAdapter as the JDA README explains.

Comment: I just realised that the bug was due to the improper naming of classes, is there any documentation that says the proper names for them? i wrote onMessageReaction as a name and it didnt get highlighted as yellow untill i wrote onMessageReactionAdd as per your code.

Comment: Just look at the methods in ListenerAdapter, you are overriding those methods, so your names and parameters must be identical.